# How to get buffering status from video_player flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter

I used `video_player` plugin in my app to load videos from network. I want to display `CircularProgressIndicator` if the video is currently buffering.

Is there any way to get buffering status from the controller? I checked the class and only found how much of the video is buffered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_controller.value.isBuffering` which return true if the video is currently buffering.

Comment: Isn't there a callback for this? Am I supposed to check if isBufferring is true or false inside a timer?